# Offline Map Tiles

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3, maps

**Intro**

I am working on a mobile app (Cordova) in which user can draw polygon on Map and view their areas lately and etc. In online mode i am using google maps api 3 it is working fine.

**Requirement**

Now i want to provide map view to users if they have no internet access but it cannot done by Google Map as their licences mentioned. So i use [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) maps for offline use. Now i want to download tiles only specific region that user define in online mode (polygons).
So my question is that how do i achieve that functionality to download tiles only given polygon points. I want tiles only on demand of given polygon

**Try following**

I use [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobac/?source=typ_redirect) to download tiles but it download separately. SO that will increase my app size i don't want that. So when user using app he/she can download if they want.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: no i didn't find any solution yet